# .query() rendering wrong path

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My function is using `query()` method to display all the tasks. The problem is that it's referring to `users/tasks?status=completed`.

And I need `users/:user_id/tasks?status=completed`.
 How can I solve it?

```
var app = angular.module('Todolist', ['ngResource']);

  app.factory('Task', [
    '$resource', function($resource) {
      return $resource('/users/:user_id/tasks/', {id: '@id'}, {update: {method: 'PUT'}});
     }
   ]);

  app.controller('TasksCtrl', [
    '$scope', 'Task', function($scope, Task) {

      $scope.user = current_user

      $scope.tasks = Task.query(
        status: 'incompleted'
      );

    }
   }
  ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update you controller

```
 app.controller('TasksCtrl', [
    '$scope', 'Task', function($scope, Task) {
     $scope.user = null; //current_user please define this variable it will cause for undefined error
    $scope.tasks = Task.query({status: 'completed', user_id : 12}); //'12' is user id , you can pass dynamically

 }]);
```

Factory code is  :

```
app..factory('Task', [
    '$resource', function($resource) {
      return $resource('/users/:user_id/tasks/',
      {user_id: '@user_id'},
      {update: {method: 'PUT'}});
   }
]);
```

[**Working plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/VKMwnvTVKqtgGgHUZerv?p=preview)

Comment: @PankajParkar Please see my comments on your answer

Comment: I removed my downvote and answer too.. as don't wanted to discourage to anyone  :) Impressed by your childish nature. LOL :D